# Forward events from UIScrollView to UIButton

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, uibutton, touch

I got an `UIButton` inside an `UIScrollView`. The problem is that the `UIButton` is not big enough to fill the entire `UIScrollView`. I'd like to be able to forward the touch events in other areas of the `UIScrollView` to the `UIButton`. Here's a screenshot of my app:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/405/img1410.png/

Does anyone knows how to do that?

Comment: iOS(iPhone, iPod touch and iPad)

Answer (score 1):

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(itemTouched:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

- (void) itemTouched:(UIButton*) sender
{
  [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(doSomething:) withObject:sender waitUntilDone:NO];
}
```

The highlight of `UIButton` can be shown before call `doSomething` method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can forward touches in that manner, but I guess you could resize the UIButton to fill the whole scrollView and make the content not stretch, such that it looks identical, but there'd be a much bigger UIButton.

Answer (score 0):

To propagate touches down the chain to a sub view use:

```
[mychild touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
```

in your scrollView's touchesBegan.